# Tensor flow can't find trained model

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to train a model, but I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 289, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 543, in evaluate
    log_progress=log_progress)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 816, in _evaluate_model
    % self._model_dir)
tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators._sklearn.NotFittedError: Couldn't find trained model at /var/folders/hd/96gvrtvn66dcnbntwn9v3skh0000gp/T/tmpq4Q43n.
```

This is my code:

```
data = pandas.read_csv(data_file,sep=";",names=header)
CONTINUOUS_COLUMNS = ['rsi','stochk','stochd']
CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS = []

def input_fn(df):
  # Creates a dictionary mapping from each continuous feature column name (k) to
  # the values of that column stored in a constant Tensor.
  continuous_cols = {k: tf.constant(df[k].values)
                     for k in CONTINUOUS_COLUMNS}
  # Creates a dictionary mapping from each categorical feature column name (k)
  # to the values of that column stored in a tf.SparseTensor.
  categorical_cols = {k: tf.SparseTensor(
      indices=[[i, 0] for i in range(df[k].size)],
      values=df[k].values,
      dense_shape=[df[k].size, 1])
                      for k in CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS}
  # Merges the two dictionaries into one.
  feature_cols = dict(continuous_cols.items() + categorical_cols.items())
  # Converts the label column into a constant Tensor.
  label = tf.constant(df[LABEL_COLUMN].values)
  # Returns the feature columns and the label.
  return feature_cols, label


def train_input_fn():
  return input_fn(df_train)

def eval_input_fn():
  return input_fn(df_test)

model_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()


CONTINUOUS_COLUMNS = ['rsi','stochk','stochd']

### defining the model
m = tf.contrib.learn.LinearClassifier(feature_columns=[
        data['rsi'],
        data['stochk'],
        data['stochd']

    ],
  model_dir=model_dir)


m.fit(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=200)

results = m.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_fn, steps=1)
```

When I check the folder:
/var/folders/hd/96gvrtvn66dcnbntwn9v3skh0000gp/T/tmpq4Q43n

There is no file there.
But I'm following this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/wide) and I didn't get how to have a file in the tmp dir.

How can I fix this?

EDIT

The output of train_input_fn()

```
train_input_fn()
({'stochd': <tf.Tensor 'Const_10:0' shape=(177144,) dtype=float64>, 'rsi': <tf.Tensor 'Const_8:0' shape=(177144,) dtype=float64>, 'stochk': <tf.Tensor 'Const_9:0' shape=(177144,) dtype=float64>}, <tf.Tensor 'Const_11:0' shape=(177144,) dtype=string>)
```

Comment: Have you checked the permissions on the directories in that path?  Can you create a file there with `touch`?

Comment: `fit()` method should create a trained model in the dir. Do you have write permissions? Do you actually feed any data to `fit()`?

Comment: @verisimilidude Yes, I added write permissions with chmod 777 /var/folders/hd/96gvrtvn66dcnbntwn9v3skh0000gp/T/tmpq4Q43n. But still I get nothing on it.

Comment: @AlexanderSvetkin I used as input train_input_fn which is function as you can see in the code. I edited the question with the result of train_input_fn

Comment: @FilipeFerminiano Did you find the answer ???

Comment: no, i didn't fount it